# I sang, got really light headed and it wont go away. What should I do?

Tags: voice, health, choir

So one day I was singing and I started getting a bit light headed so I paused for a bit and kept on going, but the lightheadedness only got worse and worse until the point that I was about to faint, thankfully my aunt managed to help me into the car and we drove off home so I could get some rest. (I do want to mention that it was unusual hot on the room i was singing). I got home tried to wait it out, got some rest, but the lightheadedness and the dissiness didn't go away it just simply got a tiny bit better. a bit later in the evening my blood pressure had gone way up, and as far as I know i never had high blood pressure before, I just physically couldn't. I always ate healthy, workout, in my opinion I'm a pretty fit/health guy. So anyways, I went to sleep hoping that it would go away, woke up, the lightheadedness did get a bit better but the dissiness did not. And no I did not take any alcohol or drugs ever. Any clue what's going on with me? How to fix it?

Comment: Please see a doctor right away.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry to hear you're not feeling well. It's not wise to look for a medical diagnose on the internet, and especially not on a music forum. Assume that the singing was only the trigger and not the root cause, anyway. You know your body best. So, if it isn't getting better or you feel you need help, see a doctor.